# Running pylint scoped to particular PR

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pull-request, pylint, pre-commit.com

In my opinion, `pylint` is a great tool and I love it.  However, some individuals don't prefer `pylint`, and I find myself collaborating on projects with individuals who don't like `pylint`.

Our CI pipeline has multiple workflows, one of which is an optional "lint" workflow that runs `pylint`.  Several PRs have been merged with `pylint` not passing, so the lint workflow will never pass when run on the entire repo.

**My question**: how can I run `pylint` on just the files associated with a particular pull request?

That way, I can bring the lint workflow's `pylint` step to pass again, despite `pylint` failing when run on the full repo.

**Food for Thought**

We use `pre-commit` to run `flake8`/`isort`/`black`.  I am wondering if there's some way to invoke `pre-commit` a second time in CI, with a second config (specified via `--config`) to feed `pylint` with just the files scoped to a given PR.

Requested detail: we use Git/GitHub.

Comment: You could probably cobble something together with `git diff`/`git log` and friends (you are using git, right? Github? Gitlab?). Though what's the point if you the project doesn't follow the style anyway? It might be easier - and more maintainable - to fix up the repo to match the lint or to declare it a lost cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stating the obvious first, if you want to use pylint on a project you need to convince your team that they want to use pylint so everyone is on board.

Second I think you already know that, but you can use git tricks to do what you want. For example `git show --pretty="" --name-only HEAD|xargs pylint`.

This is not going to fix your change management problem though. pylint can be adopted more easily by using its features to disable the messages you don't want to fix (yet?).

What I advise you do it create a `.pylintrc` and disable globally messages that would be too long or not worth it to fix right now.

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]

# Enable the message, report, category or checker with the given id(s). You can
# either give multiple identifier separated by comma (,) or put this option
# multiple time (only on the command line, not in the configuration file where
# it should appear only once). See also the "--disable" option for examples.
enable=
    use-symbolic-message-instead,
    useless-suppression,

# Disable the message, report, category or checker with the given id(s). You
# can either give multiple identifiers separated by comma (,) or put this
# option multiple times (only on the command line, not in the configuration
# file where it should appear only once).You can also use "--disable=all" to
# disable everything first and then re-enable specific checks. For example, if
# you want to run only the similarities checker, you can use "--disable=all
# --enable=similarities". If you want to run only the classes checker, but have
# no Warning level messages displayed, use"--disable=all --enable=classes
# --disable=W"

disable=
    attribute-defined-outside-init
```

If you only have a few message instead of disabling globally, [disable them locally directly in the code or per-file](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html).

```py
# All the violations on a single line
a, b = ... # pylint: disable=unbalanced-tuple-unpacking

All the violations on the following line
# pylint: disable-next=unbalanced-tuple-unpacking
a, b = ...
```

Do that until you identify *real* problems that are worth the fix in the current state of your project. Then show the value pylint bring to the team. Once  you've done that you can run pylint in CI and only new/valuable problems will be shown by the CI. And you can remove disables progressively.

There's [a feature request to facilitate your use case in pylint by creating a baseline of the repository](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/5403). This would make sure that only new messages would get reported. There's [another one to help with the triaging of important issues vs nitpicky one](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/5604). It would make it easier to disable the message without thinking a lot about what you do. But it's not in pylint yet (as of 2.13.0).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response @PierreSassoulas!  I was away on an extended trip, sorry for the delayed response.  If you're curious, I posted an answer to this question showing how I integrated using `pre-commit` over the DIY `git show` approach (though it's just as good).  Thank you again also for all your work on pylint, I am a fan!

Answer (score 0):

To invoke `pylint` as desired, I ended up leveraging `pre-commit` in CI with a secondary config like so:

```sh
pre-commit run --show-diff-on-failure --config .pre-commit-lint-config.yaml \
--from-ref origin/develop --to-ref HEAD
```

Inspired by [pylint docs on pre-commit](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/pre-commit-integration.html), here's a subset of my `.pre-commit-lint-config.yaml`:

```yaml
---
default_language_version:
  python: python3.10

repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pylint
        name: pylint src
        alias: pylint-src
        language: system
        files: ^src/
        types: [python]
        entry: pylint
        args:
          - "-rn"  # Only display messages
          - "-sn"  # Don't display the score
          - "--rcfile=src/pyproject.toml"
```